# Javascript - points calculation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I created a simple survey, where every answer to a question gives you different amount of the points. I don't want the points to be in the value itself so I put it into the javascript.

I cannot find the error why in the console the querySelector throws null:
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

HTML code:

```
<fieldset id="question1">
    <p style="font-weight:600;">What's your favorite color?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a1" required>Red</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a2" required>Blue</label><br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="question2">
    <p style="font-weight:600;">How old are you?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2a1">over 18</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2a2">under 18</label><br>
</fieldset>
```

Name represent question number and id represent question number together with answer number.

Javascript

```
var points = {
    "q1": {"q1a1": 0, "q1a2": 1},
    "q2": {"q2a1": 0, "q2a2": 3}
};
var totalPoints = 0;

function calculatePoints() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= numQuestions; i++) {
        var selectedAnswer = document.querySelector('input[name="q' + i + '"]:checked').id;
    totalPoints += points[selectedAnswer];
    }
}
```

I tried to add the calculation of the points into the listener itself but it also throws the same error. Just want the number of points being taken from variable based on the selectedAnswer and calculated and send to the next page with results.

Comment: It means that there is no checked radio.

Comment: If you check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), `document.querySelector` returns `null` when no matching element is found.  So your next debugging step is to examine the exact selector being used at that time and determine why you expect that element to exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculate the points even on checkboxes that don't have a checked radiobox -> can't find a DOM Node -> null -> calls `.id` on null. So, you either check that every "question" has an answer OR add a check if the `document.querySelector(...)` returns null. It added an if-clause in the snippet and called the `.id` after the condition.

```js
var points = {
    "q1": {"q1a1": 0, "q1a2": 1},
    "q2": {"q2a1": 0, "q2a2": 3}
};
var totalPoints = 0;

function calculatePoints() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    let questionKey = `q${i}`;
    var selectedAnswer = document.querySelector(`input[name="${questionKey}"]:checked`);

    // that's what I added
    if (selectedAnswer) {
      totalPoints += points[questionKey][selectedAnswer.id]; // calling .id here
    };
  }
  console.log({ totalPoints });
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="question1">
    <p style="font-weight:600;">What's your favorite color?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a1" required>Red</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1a2" required>Blue</label><br>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="question2">
    <p style="font-weight:600;">How old are you?</p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2a1">over 18</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2a2">under 18</label><br>
</fieldset>

<button type="button" onclick="calculatePoints()">
  calculate
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed the error but the points still not being calculated and showed or passed to the form page.

Comment: @BenStephens yeah, just realized & updated the script.